# SUMIF with multiple criteria and first instance only

Tags: excel, sumifs

I'm trying to sum all of the data in column D that have either a yes in the primary or secondary category, but only include the first instance of that value. In the example below, the sum would be 3 (1 for A, 2 for B). Please help!!

```
Area    Primary Site    Secondary Site  Value
A        yes              no              1
B        yes              no              2
A        no               yes             1
C        no               no              3
```

Comment: are the values always the same for the same area?

Comment: Yes, the values are always the same for the same area

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((($B$2:$B$5="yes")+($C$2:$C$5="yes"))*$D$2:$D$5)/((COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$5,$A$2:$A$5,$B$2:$B$5,"yes")+COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$5,$A$2:$A$5,$C$2:$C$5,"yes"))+(($B$2:$B$5="no")*($C$2:$C$5="no"))))
```

[image]

Comment: I follow the first part of the sumproduct, its the whole divide by the counif I am lost in, but I am going to safely assume this part deals with first occurance.

Comment: it actually divides it by the number of occurrences of each specific area.  `A` gets pickup twice but since it exists twice it returns `0.5` instead of `1` to the SUMPRODUCT.  But since it gets picked up twice it ends up being `1`.  which is why I asked if the the value per area is the same.

Comment: if row six had an A, but primary and secondary were both NO, that A does not get included because the countif wont include it correct?

Comment: @ForwardEd correct the numerator would return `0` and `0` would get added to the running total.  And the Countifs() would still only return `2` to the numerator on the two lines that had `yes` in one of the columns.

Comment: What is the ="no" part trying to do? avoiding a divide by 0 error?

Comment: @ForwardEd making sure I do not get `#DIV/0` error.  So when those are TRUE Everything else is returning `0` and we get `0/1` or `0`

Comment: Took me awhile to wrap my brain around what the code was doing, but it worked for my 20,000+ rows of data!

Answer (score 1):

Good evening.

`=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(B2:C5="yes",MATCH(A2:A5,A2:A5,0)),ROW(B2:C5)-MIN(ROW(B2:C5))+1),D2:D5))`

Regards

***Note to Stackoverflow editors**: kindly do not edit out my initial greeting (or replace with e.g. "Use:"). The implication, i.e. that salutations are to be considered 'extraneous' to a post, is worrying to say the least.*

Comment: It should probably be noted that the formula is an array formula and needs the CSE.

Comment: while I agree with your stance, it is specifically stated that one should not use greetings [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior).  It will not be me that removes it but someone may, quoting the linked documentation.

Comment: @ScottCraner Yes, thanks. I forgot to mention that this is an array formula.

Comment: @ScottCraner And thanks also for the link. I had wrongly presumed that such cuts were the personal decisions of one or two overzealous editors. That it is site policy means that, unfortunately, Stackoverflow and I will now have to part ways. I might just add in parting that it would seem a touch inconsistent that the expected behaviour requests users to "be welcoming", yet disallows greetings, apparently so as to reduce "noise", the mere two letters which form the most common and international of greetings evidently falling under this definition. Keep up your good work.